# Giltab CI Job stuck because the runner tag value hasn’t been assigned

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CICD configuration that looks something like this:

```
.rule_template: &rule_configuration
  rules:
    - changes:
        - file/dev/script1.txt
      variables:
        DESTINATION_HOST: somehost1
        RUNNER_TAG: somerunner1
    - changes:
        - file/test/script1.txt
      variables:
        DESTINATION_HOST: somehost2
        RUNNER_TAG: somerunner2

default:
  tags:
    - scripts

stages:
  - lint

deploy scripts 1/6:
  <<: *rule_configuration
  tags:
    - ${RUNNER_TAG}
  stage: lint
  script: |
    echo "Add linting here!"
    
....
```

In short, which runner to choose depends on which file was changed, hence the runner tag has to be conditionally decided. However, these jobs never execute and the value of never gets assigned as i always get:

```
This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them: ${RUNNER_TAG}
```

Any idea, what is it this way and what can I do to resolve this?

```
gitlab-runner --version
Version:      14.7.0
Git revision: 98daeee0
Git branch:   14-7-stable
GO version:   go1.17.5
Built:        2022-01-19T17:11:48+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Which version of GitLab are you running? It might be good to edit this information in your question. Variables in runner tags are available for versions [14.1](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#use-cicd-variables-in-tags) and above.

Comment: @lyzlisa done and the version seems to be `14.7.0`

Answer (score 0):

Tags map jobs to runners. I tag my runners with the type of executor they use, e.g. - `shell`, `docker`.

Based on the error message, you do not have any runners with the tag `${RUNNER_TAG}`, which means that it is not resolving the variable the way you want it to.

Instead of combining rules like this, make separate jobs for each, and a rule for each to say when to trigger it.

Comment: I beleive the actual issue is why its resolving the variable `${RUNNER_TAG}` which certainly exists. The other way would be if i say, dirty its a complex scenario with different runners required for different types of files, creating separate job for each would resulting in copy pasting jobs several times, of course neither elegant and very error prone keeping in mind maintaining it.

Comment: Add `printenv | grep RUNNER_TAG` to the top of the `script:` section of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to verify your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue, and similar issues many times while trying to do some dynamic pipelines for a multi-client environment.

The config you have above *should* work for your purposes to the best of my knowledge, but since it is not there is another way to accomplish this with [trigger jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#trigger).

Create a trigger job for each possible runner tag. You can use `extends` to reduce the total code required for this.

`gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - trigger
  - lint

.trigger:
  stage: trigger
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: ./lint-job.yml
    strategy: depend


trigger-lint-script1:
  extends:
    - .trigger
  variables:
    RUNNER_TAG: somerunner1
  rules:
    - changes:
        - file/dev/script1.txt


trigger-lint-script2:
  extends:
    - .trigger
  variables:
    RUNNER_TAG: somerunner2
  rules:
    - changes:
        - file/dev/script2.txt
```

Create a trigger job with associated rules for each possible tag. This way you can change more than one of the specified files in a single commit with no issues. Define the triggered job in lint-job.yml

`lint-job.yml`

```
deploy scripts 1/6:
  tags: [$RUNNER_TAG]
  stage: lint
  script: |
    echo "Add linting here!"
```

There are other ways to accomplish this, but this method is by far the simplest and cleanest for this particular use.